# How do I group category properties within an infinite subcategory

Tags: laravel

I have a collection like below.

Including all nested subcategories of this collection.

I want to group by "`type`" column under all "`categoryprop`".

How can I do it?

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "parent_id":null,
      "order":0,
      "name":"Home Page",
      "slug":"\/",
      "type":"home-page",
      "status":"1",
      "menu":"0",
      "megamenu":"0",
      "megamcol":0,
      "megamrow":0,
      "menuheadershow":"0",
      "menufootershow":"0",
      "menuiconbg":"",
      "menuicon":"",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "subcategory":[
         
      ],
      "categoryprop":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "parent_id":null,
      "order":1,
      "name":"Hosting",
      "slug":"hosting",
      "type":"hosting",
      "status":"1",
      "menu":"0",
      "megamenu":"1",
      "megamcol":2,
      "megamrow":4,
      "menuheadershow":"1",
      "menufootershow":"1",
      "menuiconbg":null,
      "menuicon":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "subcategory":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":0,
            "name":"Web Hosting",
            "slug":"web-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"primary-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-server",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               {
                  "id":15,
                  "parent_id":3,
                  "order":0,
                  "name":"Web Hosting",
                  "slug":"web-hosting",
                  "type":"hosting",
                  "status":"1",
                  "menu":"0",
                  "megamenu":"0",
                  "megamcol":0,
                  "megamrow":0,
                  "menuheadershow":"0",
                  "menufootershow":"0",
                  "menuiconbg":"primary-bg",
                  "menuicon":"fas fa-server",
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "subcategory":[
                     
                  ],
                  "categoryprop":[
                     {
                        "id":3,
                        "category_id":15,
                        "order":0,
                        "type":"menudescription",
                        "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u0131",
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "categorycontent":[
                           {
                              "id":5,
                              "categoryprop_id":3,
                              "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":1,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":1,
                                 "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                 "symbol":"TR",
                                 "code":"tr",
                                 "default":1,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "id":6,
                              "categoryprop_id":3,
                              "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":2,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":2,
                                 "name":"English",
                                 "symbol":"EN",
                                 "code":"en_us",
                                 "default":0,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":4,
                        "category_id":3,
                        "order":0,
                        "type":"menudescription",
                        "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u01312",
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "categorycontent":[
                           {
                              "id":7,
                              "categoryprop_id":4,
                              "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":1,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":1,
                                 "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                 "symbol":"TR",
                                 "code":"tr",
                                 "default":1,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "id":8,
                              "categoryprop_id":4,
                              "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":2,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":2,
                                 "name":"English",
                                 "symbol":"EN",
                                 "code":"en_us",
                                 "default":0,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "category_id":3,
                  "order":0,
                  "type":"menudescription",
                  "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u0131",
                  "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                  "categorycontent":[
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "categoryprop_id":1,
                        "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                        "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                        "image":null,
                        "lang_id":1,
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "lang":{
                           "id":1,
                           "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                           "symbol":"TR",
                           "code":"tr",
                           "default":1,
                           "created_at":null,
                           "updated_at":null
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "id":2,
                        "categoryprop_id":1,
                        "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                        "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                        "image":null,
                        "lang_id":2,
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "lang":{
                           "id":2,
                           "name":"English",
                           "symbol":"EN",
                           "code":"en_us",
                           "default":0,
                           "created_at":null,
                           "updated_at":null
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "category_id":3,
                  "order":0,
                  "type":"menudescription",
                  "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u01312",
                  "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                  "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                  "categorycontent":[
                     {
                        "id":3,
                        "categoryprop_id":2,
                        "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                        "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                        "image":null,
                        "lang_id":1,
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "lang":{
                           "id":1,
                           "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                           "symbol":"TR",
                           "code":"tr",
                           "default":1,
                           "created_at":null,
                           "updated_at":null
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "id":4,
                        "categoryprop_id":2,
                        "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                        "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                        "image":null,
                        "lang_id":2,
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "lang":{
                           "id":2,
                           "name":"English",
                           "symbol":"EN",
                           "code":"en_us",
                           "default":0,
                           "created_at":null,
                           "updated_at":null
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":1,
            "name":"Wordpress Hosting",
            "slug":"wordpress-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"accent-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-box",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":2,
            "name":"Linux Hosting",
            "slug":"linux-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"secondary-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-cloud",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":3,
            "name":"S\u0131n\u0131rs\u0131z Hosting",
            "slug":"sinirsiz-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"twitter-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-infinity",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         }
         
      ]
   },
   
]
```

The result I expected:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "parent_id":null,
      "order":0,
      "name":"Home Page",
      "slug":"\/",
      "type":"home-page",
      "status":"1",
      "menu":"0",
      "megamenu":"0",
      "megamcol":0,
      "megamrow":0,
      "menuheadershow":"0",
      "menufootershow":"0",
      "menuiconbg":"",
      "menuicon":"",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "subcategory":[
         
      ],
      "categoryprop":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "parent_id":null,
      "order":1,
      "name":"Hosting",
      "slug":"hosting",
      "type":"hosting",
      "status":"1",
      "menu":"0",
      "megamenu":"1",
      "megamcol":2,
      "megamrow":4,
      "menuheadershow":"1",
      "menufootershow":"1",
      "menuiconbg":null,
      "menuicon":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "subcategory":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":0,
            "name":"Web Hosting",
            "slug":"web-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"primary-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-server",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               {
                  "id":15,
                  "parent_id":3,
                  "order":0,
                  "name":"Web Hosting",
                  "slug":"web-hosting",
                  "type":"hosting",
                  "status":"1",
                  "menu":"0",
                  "megamenu":"0",
                  "megamcol":0,
                  "megamrow":0,
                  "menuheadershow":"0",
                  "menufootershow":"0",
                  "menuiconbg":"primary-bg",
                  "menuicon":"fas fa-server",
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "subcategory":[
                     
                  ],
                  "categoryprop":[
                     {
                        "menudescription":[
                           {
                              "id":3,
                              "category_id":15,
                              "order":0,
                              "type":"menudescription",
                              "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u0131",
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "categorycontent":[
                                 {
                                    "id":5,
                                    "categoryprop_id":3,
                                    "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                                    "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                                    "image":null,
                                    "lang_id":1,
                                    "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "lang":{
                                       "id":1,
                                       "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                       "symbol":"TR",
                                       "code":"tr",
                                       "default":1,
                                       "created_at":null,
                                       "updated_at":null
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "id":6,
                                    "categoryprop_id":3,
                                    "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                                    "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                                    "image":null,
                                    "lang_id":2,
                                    "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "lang":{
                                       "id":2,
                                       "name":"English",
                                       "symbol":"EN",
                                       "code":"en_us",
                                       "default":0,
                                       "created_at":null,
                                       "updated_at":null
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           {
                              "id":4,
                              "category_id":3,
                              "order":0,
                              "type":"menudescription",
                              "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u01312",
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "categorycontent":[
                                 {
                                    "id":7,
                                    "categoryprop_id":4,
                                    "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                                    "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                                    "image":null,
                                    "lang_id":1,
                                    "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "lang":{
                                       "id":1,
                                       "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                       "symbol":"TR",
                                       "code":"tr",
                                       "default":1,
                                       "created_at":null,
                                       "updated_at":null
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "id":8,
                                    "categoryprop_id":4,
                                    "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                                    "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                                    "image":null,
                                    "lang_id":2,
                                    "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                                    "lang":{
                                       "id":2,
                                       "name":"English",
                                       "symbol":"EN",
                                       "code":"en_us",
                                       "default":0,
                                       "created_at":null,
                                       "updated_at":null
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               {
                  "menudescription":[
                     {
                        "id":1,
                        "category_id":3,
                        "order":0,
                        "type":"menudescription",
                        "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u0131",
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "categorycontent":[
                           {
                              "id":1,
                              "categoryprop_id":1,
                              "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":1,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":1,
                                 "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                 "symbol":"TR",
                                 "code":"tr",
                                 "default":1,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "id":2,
                              "categoryprop_id":1,
                              "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":2,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":2,
                                 "name":"English",
                                 "symbol":"EN",
                                 "code":"en_us",
                                 "default":0,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "id":2,
                        "category_id":3,
                        "order":0,
                        "type":"menudescription",
                        "name":"Men\u00fc A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u01312",
                        "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                        "categorycontent":[
                           {
                              "id":3,
                              "categoryprop_id":2,
                              "title":"Bu bir denemedir",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":1,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":1,
                                 "name":"T\u00fcrk\u00e7e",
                                 "symbol":"TR",
                                 "code":"tr",
                                 "default":1,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "id":4,
                              "categoryprop_id":2,
                              "title":"Bur bir deneme",
                              "content":"Bu bir deneme",
                              "image":null,
                              "lang_id":2,
                              "created_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "updated_at":"2022-09-09T16:37:02.000000Z",
                              "lang":{
                                 "id":2,
                                 "name":"English",
                                 "symbol":"EN",
                                 "code":"en_us",
                                 "default":0,
                                 "created_at":null,
                                 "updated_at":null
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":1,
            "name":"Wordpress Hosting",
            "slug":"wordpress-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"accent-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-box",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":2,
            "name":"Linux Hosting",
            "slug":"linux-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"secondary-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-cloud",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "parent_id":2,
            "order":3,
            "name":"S\u0131n\u0131rs\u0131z Hosting",
            "slug":"sinirsiz-hosting",
            "type":"hosting",
            "status":"1",
            "menu":"0",
            "megamenu":"0",
            "megamcol":0,
            "megamrow":0,
            "menuheadershow":"0",
            "menufootershow":"0",
            "menuiconbg":"twitter-bg",
            "menuicon":"fas fa-infinity",
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null,
            "subcategory":[
               
            ],
            "categoryprop":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "parent_id":null,
      "order":1,
      "name":"Alan Ad\u0131",
      "slug":"alanadi",
      "type":"alanadi",
      "status":"1",
      "menu":"0",
      "megamenu":"0",
      "megamcol":0,
      "megamrow":0,
      "menuheadershow":"0",
      "menufootershow":"0",
      "menuiconbg":null,
      "menuicon":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "subcategory":[
         
      ],
      "categoryprop":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: something like this: $grouped = $collection->groupBy('account_id');

Comment: No, it's definitely not like that.

Comment: @Pasalar Can you add a sample array representation of the expected result to your question?

Comment: @OnurUslu I added the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the array is too complicated. I think you should simplify it somehow.

I have two solution methods. These are the Laravel way and the pure PHP way.

**Method-1 (Laravel)**

Before starting this, you must ensure that values of the "`subcategory` and `categoryprop`" are instances of the `Illuminate\Support\Collection`
. If they are not an instance of a Collection object, use Method-2.

```php
class Method1
{
    public function handle() {
        // ...
        var_dump($categories->map($this, 'mapper'));
    }

    public function mapper($collection) {

        // If it has sub-categories, map them
        if (optional($collection['subcategory'])->count()) {
            $collection['subcategory'] = $collection['subcategory']->map([$this, 'mapper']);
        }

        $lastItemIndex = $collection->count() - 1;

        // If it is an array of categories, map them.
        if (isset($collection[$lastItemIndex])) {
            return $collection->map([$this, 'mapper']);
        }

        // If there is no item in $collection['categoryprop']
        if (0 >= optional($collection->get('categoryprop'))->count()) {
            return $collection;
        }

        $collection['categoryprop'] = $collection['categoryprop']->groupBy('type');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**Method-2 (Pure PHP)**

```php
class Method2
{
    public function handle() {
        // ...
        var_dump($this->groupByCategoryProp($categories));
    }

    public function groupByItemKey($collection, $key) {
        $generatedList = [];

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $type = $item[$key];

            $generatedList[$type][] = $item;
        }

        return $generatedList;
    }

    public function groupByCategoryProp($collection) {

        // If it has sub-categories, map them.
        if (isset($collection['subcategory']) && 0 < count($collection['subcategory']) ) {
            $subCategory = $this->groupByCategoryProp($collection['subcategory']);

            $collection['subcategory'] = $subCategory;
        }

        $lastItemIndex = count($collection) - 1;

        // If it is an array of categories, map them.
        if (isset($collection[$lastItemIndex])) {
            foreach ($collection as $i => $category) {
                $collection[$i] = $this->groupByCategoryProp($category);
            }

            return $collection;
        }

        // If there is no categoryprop
        if (! isset($collection['categoryprop'])) {
            return $collection;
        }

        // If there is no item in $collection['categoryprop']
        if (0 === count($collection['categoryprop']) ) {
            return $collection;
        }

        $collection['categoryprop'] = $this->groupByItemKey($collection['categoryprop'], 'type') ;

        return $collection;
    }
}
```